# Enum parsing. String to Anchor

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a string variable with the value `"Top;Left"`. Is it possible to easily parse this to `Control.Anchor` (without using `if`'s)?

`Enum.Parse` doesn't work because `Anchor` can take a value, for example, `Top;Left;`, but the `AnchorEnum` can only take `Top`, or `Left`, or `Right`, or `Bottom`, or `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to parse this without iterating over each option.

```
var s = "Top;Left";
s = s.Replace(";", ", ");
var e = Enum.Parse(typeof(AnchorStyles), s);
```

The only gotcha is it has to be comma separated, not semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Split`, parse each of them individually using `Enum.TryParse` or `Enum.Parse`, then `OR` the resulting values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to parse this, but it's pretty easy to write something that does:

```
public static AnchorStyles Parse(string str)
{
    return str.Split(';')
        .Select(s => (AnchorStyles) Enum.Parse(typeof (AnchorStyles), s, true))
        .Aggregate((a1, a2) => a1 | a2);
    }
}
```

Comment: To downvoter: Just because someone may do something different than you but achieve the same result does not deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string value ="Top;Left";
        var anchor =(System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles), value.Replace(";", " , "))
```